# Problema con la posición de botón css

Tags: css

Quiero hacer que el botón de la imagen del clip se coloque a un lado de la caja de texto cuando se visualice en una pantalla chica

tengo este codigo css:

```
<style>
.adjuntar
{
    width: 34px;
    height: 27px;
    background-image: url(../img/adjuntar.png);
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.boton
{
    left: 36%;
    top: 25%;
    position: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .boton
    {
     left: 500%;
     top: 80%;
     position: fixed;
    }   
}
</style>
```

Tengo este codigo html:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="form-registro">            
  <div class="form-group" style="width: 45%;">
   <label style="margin-right: 4px;">Parcial:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parcialVal" id="parcialVal">
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="boton" class="btn adjuntar boton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-archivos" disabled>
</form>
```

El problema es que cuando hago la pantalla chica no se mueve ese botón (el de la imagen del clip) y cuando la pantalla esta grande si se acomoda bien, ¿cual es el problema?

Asi se ve ahorita en pantalla chica y el botón del clip esta mal acomodado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**Primer paso:** Agrega la siguiente propiedad a la clase **form-group.**

```
.form-group {
   display:flex;
}
```

**Segundo Paso:** Incluye el botón dentro del **DIV form-group.**

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 45%;">
   <label style="margin-right: 4px;">Parcial:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="parcialVal" id="parcialVal">
   <input type="button" id="boton" class="btn adjuntar boton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-archivos" disabled>
</div>
```

**Tercer Paso:** Elimina o comenta la posición fija que tiene la clase **boton**.

```
/* position: fixed; */
```

Comment: no funciona como me lo estas diciendo

Comment: Asegúrate de comentar todos los position: fixed

Comment: Ya comente todos los position: fixed y nada ahora el botón lo pone debajo de la caja de texto y lo que quiero es que lo ponga a un lado de la caja de texto